# Change color of scrollbar of listbox in ASP.NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, listbox, scrollbar, backcolor

How to change the color of scrollbar of a listbox in ASP.NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS to change the colours, this will allow you to play and help generate the CSS for you.
[CSS colored scrollbar code](http://www.maketemplate.com/scrollbar/)